# ASP.NET via mono on linux?

Tags: linux, asp.net, mono

Has anyone tried running an ASP.NET project via mono on a linux server? Can it be done? was the performance good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am successfully running an ASP.NET MVC application on Ubuntu 8.04 LTS in a Rackspace Cloud Server.

If you are planning on working with ASP.NET v2.0 and .NET 3.5 including LINQ, I suggest the [following procedure](http://blog.ruski.co.za/page/Install-Mono-on-Ubuntu.aspx), which has led to my own setup. I am still struggling with some HTTPS requests under Apache but with xsp it all works just like on a Windows Server 2008 running IIS.

Comment: Excellent link. I got it running with no problems with it. The script was especially nice :D

Answer (score 2):

I've never tried this, but according to [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET), Mono does have an ASP.NET implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm successfully setup BlogEngine.Net on my domain blog.extriko.com running ubuntu server, lighttpd and the [mono-fastcgi-server2](http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI)